Uniquess of the solution to the linear differential operator tied to Kolmogorov forward equation
Given a set of smooth functions $\{\psi\}$ with bounded support on $\mathbb{R}^d$, let us define the linear differential operator $L$ to be
$$
L\psi = - (\nabla \psi(x))^T Bx + \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(\nabla^2 \psi(x) C),
$$
where $B, C$ are $d$ by $d$ positive definite matrices. For a given set of probability distributions $\{\mu\}$, is it true that
$$
\int L\psi(x) \mu(dx) = 0,
$$
holds only for Gaussian distribution $\mu$ with mean zero and covariance $\Sigma$ satisfying $B\Sigma + \Sigma B^T = C$?
It seems like this is closely related to the uniqueness of the solution of the Fokker-Planck/Kolmogorov Forward Equation, which is often derived from the underlying SDE. But purely, from operator perspective, is the above true?

you can try assuming $\mu(dx)=\rho(x)dx$ and do integration by parts to get some ODE-system for $\rho(x)$ i.e. $\int \psi(x) L^{*}\rho(x) dx=0$.

If I restrict it to probability distributions with twice differentiable Lebesgue density, I can show the uniqueness using PDE knowledge, but I am asking it for a general set of probability distribution.
